# Confused about the static function using static variable

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and got confused when using static methods..
This file defined a class A-----classa.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
class A{
    public:
        static void func1();
        static void func2();
    private:
        static std::map<int, std::string> testmap;
};
```

I hope the other functions in this class can share the same map----classa.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include "classa.h"

void A::func1(){
    std::cout<<"func1#####"<<std::endl;
    A::testmap.insert(std::make_pair(1, "func1"));
    std::cout<< testmap[1] << std::endl;
}
void A::func2(){
    std::cout<<"func2#####"<<std::endl;
    A::testmap.insert(std::make_pair(2, "func2"));
    std::cout<< testmap[2] << std::endl;
}
int main(){ 
    A::func1();
    A::func2();
}
```

But it does not work and got this err:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "A::testmap", referenced from:
      A::func1() in classa-0798d3.o
      A::func2() in classa-0798d3.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I'd appreciate it if I could get some help. Thanks!

Comment: You only *declare* the `testmap` variable, you also need to *define* it.

Comment: That programmer dude above is right. See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static) and search for "definition".

Comment: He is right just needed to initialize properly

Answer (score 0):

```
testmap  is needs to be initialized before use.
```

You can read more [here](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/static-member-functions/)

Here is the solution to your problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
class A{
   public:
      static void func1();
      static void func2();
   private:
      static std::map<int, std::string> testmap;
};

 std::map<int, std::string> A::testmap{
   []{
       map<int, std::string> v;

       v.insert(std::make_pair(1, "func1"));
       v.insert(std::make_pair(2, "func2"));

     return v;
  }() // Call the lambda right away
};

void A::func1(){
    std::cout<<"func1#####"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<< A::testmap[1] << std::endl;
}
void A::func2(){
   std::cout<<"func2#####"<<std::endl;
   std::cout<< A::testmap[2] << std::endl;
}
int main(){
  A::func1();
  A::func2();
  return 0;
}
```

[image: output:]